# Is it possible to update the Profile image when updating the Google Apps Profile image

Tags: google-plus, google-apps

The Google Apps API allows companies to make custom integrations into the mail environment. One of the things possible is to use the Profile API to keep contact information up to date. Now that our users are starting to explore the use of Google+ and Hangouts, there comes a need to keep information in sync there too.

One of the key features of the Profile API is the ability to update the profile image (detailed here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/#AddUpdating_photo). However, this API doesn't connect back into the Google+ platform by default so the profile images for the organization are getting out of sync.

Is it possible to set it up such that when one image is updated, the corresponding Google+ account's image is updated as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is not an API for updating the Google+ profile image or other profile data.